# Getting select list id and value in jquery from array of select lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectlist

I have a HTML structure like following:

```
<?php foreach($active_brand as $brand) { ?>
 <select name="selector" id="selector">
    <?php foreach($options as $option) { ?>
        <option <?php if($brand['State'] == $option) { ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?> value="<?=$brand['id']?>"><?php echo $option; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
<?php } ?>
```

This basically gives me lets say 10 select lists... Now I need to fetch the each value from the selected item in select list...

I have tried the following:

```
   $('#selector').text();
    $('#selector').change(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
```

But whenever I select anything from any of the select lists, nothing  happens... Can someone help me out ?

Comment: set different id for all select list or add any class name to select list

Comment: And how would I then dynamically fetch each value via jquery... I'd basically have to write xx times of these functions above to fetch each value ... :/

Answer (score 2):

Add class to select list;

```
<?php foreach($active_brand as $brand) { ?>
 <select class="my-select" name="selector" id="selector">
    <?php foreach($options as $option) { ?>
        <option <?php if($brand['State'] == $option) { ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?> value="<?=$brand['id']?>"><?php echo $option; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
 </select>
<?php } ?>
```

Create change event from class name:

```
 $('.my-select').change(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
        alert($(this).find("option:selected").text()); // to get text of selected option
 });
```

Comment: hey by the way how can I fetch the text from the options list??

Comment: use:    $(this).find("option:selected").text()

Comment: Hey thanks it works like a charm again ! :) One more thing.. When change function triggers, I'd like to return a confirmation message saying "Are you sure you want to change state? " If the user clicks ok, then I'll pick up the value and text from the drop-down, otherwise nothing happens if the user clicks cancel...